# phonegap Hello World Example - Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to build the Hello world example which comes along with **phonegap-2.9.1** *(phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\example)* in Eclipse. I get the app launched but when I click on "Capture Photo" It gives me following error -

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 67 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (67)
```

I have `HelloWorld-CordovaLib` project as well which is included as Lib in "Hello World" example so I don't need to build the `cordova.jar`

Another request, I am feeling its difficult to get started easily with phonegap. If you can point me to some good sites (other than phonegap itself) where I can plugin myself with phonegap community that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed camera plugin, set all the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml & add the following code in config.xml?

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```